# What does the clipped corner in the color picker's sample mean?

Tags: macos

I've noticed sometimes when using Mac OS X's color picker it has a clipped corner.

What does it mean?

[image: Color inspector with clipped corner]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got an answer over Twitter. If that user posts it here, I'll delete this answer:

> Usually means a sampled colourspace like Device RGB versus Generic RGB. Toggle the colour sliders toolbar button and click the little rainbow drop down to see the various colourspaces.

It came in two tweets, [here](http://twitter.com/davemorford/status/179263643827965952) and [here](http://twitter.com/davemorford/status/179264069214281728).

Comment: Can you add a link to the tweet?

Comment: Good idea, done.

Comment: Yes, that is the correct meaning of the corner. Since you found this, remember that you can answer your own question and select it as the correct answer so that others can benefit from your work. Good job!